# Ubuntu 23.04 Slow Internet

Tags: networking, drivers, realtek, 23.04

I have installed Ubuntu 23.04 on my HP 15 fc0025au laptop. However after install I am facing a strange problem of extremely slow internet. When I turn the WiFi off and on again, the speed comes back to normal. But is again slow after every restart.
here is the output of the `sudo lshw -C network` command

```
  *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlp2s0
       version: 00
       serial: 40:1a:58:0c:09:1a
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtw89_8852be driverversion=6.2.0-20-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.136.225 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:82 ioport:f000(size=256) memory:fce00000-fcefffff
```

and the `inxi -Nn` command

```
Network:
  Device-1: Realtek driver: rtw89_8852be
  IF: wlp2s0 state: up mac: 40:1a:58:0c:09:1a
```

My Network Card is RTL8852BE, before 23.04 happened I had to manually install drivers from this GitHub repo: https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw89
Rest assured, this is a clean install of 23.04 both Bluetooth and WiFi worked out of the box, except for this strange issue after booting.

Comment: What's your WiFi MTU?  `ip link` will tell you. For WiFi, it should be 1492, not 1500.

Comment: It is showing mtu 1500, should I change it? Why does turning wifi off and on fix it?

Comment: There's nothing indicating that this is related to mtu, and lowering mtu on one device on a network can lead to problems. Furthermore, there's no reason why wifi needs a mtu of 1492.

Comment: Try to change WiFi channel in the router if it is too loaded.

Comment: No it is not loaded. I have no interfering devices. Just the router and my laptop. And this issue only happens when Ubuntu starts as I mentioned. Turning the device wifi off and on fixes it.